# jquery masked plugin for zip codes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 text areas to which i want to apply masking.

1. Text area 1: multiple 5 digit zip codes separated by a comma and space
2. Text area 2: multiple 3 digit zip codes separated by a comma and space

So in both the cases, the allowed characters are 0-9 and comma and space.

I am having a hard time to come up with a masking for this. Can i do some thing like this with masked plugin?

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986079/how-to-allow-only-defined-characters-as-input-using-jquery) to come up with a custom plugin to allow specific keys but got into an issue with comma and ctrl+V. comma and < both have the same key code, so now taking the masking route.

```
//Multiple zip codes separated by comma and space
jQuery.fn.multipleZipCodesSeparatedByCommaAndSpaceOnly = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).keydown(function (e) {
            var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
            //alert(String.fromCharCode(key));
            if (!e.altKey && e.ctrlKey && //&&  !e.shiftKey && 
            // numbers   
                (key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
            // Numeric keypad
                (key >= 96 && key <= 105) ||
            // comma, space
                key == 188 || key == 32 ||
            // Backspace and Tab
                key == 8 || key == 9 ||
            // Home and End
                key == 35 || key == 36 ||
            // left and right arrows
                key == 37 || key == 39 ||
            // Del and Ins
                key == 46 || key == 45) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code I use for masking an input for numeric only

```
$('.numeric').keyup(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9.]/g,''))
});
```

So, changing the regex should help you achieve what you want to do.
I'm no regex expert but there are plenty of online resources !

Use this by adding a class of 'numeric' to to input field you want masked - obviously change the class name to something more suitable !

Comment: Thanks, i am putting my implementation below so that i can format it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the plugin...

```
//Multiple zip codes separated by comma and space
jQuery.fn.multipleZipCodesSeparatedByCommaAndSpaceOnly = function (method) {

    var methods = {
        init: function () {
            //keyup
            $(this).bind('input propertychange', function (e) {
                methods.ZipCodeHandle(e, $(this));
            });
        },
        ZipCodeHandle: function (e, $object) {
            $object.val($object.val().replace(/[^\d\, ]/g, ''));
        }
    };

    return this.each(function () {
        // Method calling logic
        if (methods[method])
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method)
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        else
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist');
    });

};
```